# Javascript popup window detect page loads?

Tags: javascript, popup

Lets say I have a javascript popup window (opened using `var popup = window.open()`), that is pointing to the same domain.

How can I detect each time a page is loaded from the page that opened the popup (eg. after a link is clicked on or a form is submitted) o I can check if the user performed an action? Bonus points if I can get the url and response code for the page (that is loaded in the popup).

I'd also like to note I would **not** like to rely on the loaded page within the popup to provide information (by firing events).

Comment: google analytics...

Comment: @KevinKloet I'm talking about from the context of the page that opened the pop up, in real time, for use in my application logic.